# Linear combination of powers of a function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I'm looking for a reference that studies this. Consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Is there a name for the set of functions spanned by the powers of $f$? I.e.,
$$
\left\{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_kf^k(x)|\ c_k\in\mathbb{R},\forall k\geq 0\right\}.
$$
I assume $f$ to be real analytic.
It looks like a generalization of Fourier series, but $f^k$ may not be orthogonal.

How about in general,
$$
\left\{\int_0^{\infty}g(s)f^s(x)ds|\ g(s):\mathbb{R}_+\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\right\}?
$$

Comment: Must the infinite series converge at every $x$, or at some non-empty set of $x$ values?

Comment: I’m interested in knowing what kind of functions this series can and cannot represent over some non-empty set.

Comment: And of course the series is also written $g \circ f$ where $g$ is some power series.